# Fake UDID numbers prevent iOS app installs

Tags: udid

In the Apple Store there is free software that is used to get UDID numbers from iOS devices.  I used one of these apps to get the UDID numbers from iPhones/iPad devices that are being used to test iOS apps I was creating.  Now I'm finding that since iOS 7, Apple decided for security concerns, it no longer allows programs to be able to retrieve the actual UDID number.  That being said, I have a lot of iOS devices whose UDID number start with "ffffffff" that I added to my device list in the Members Center which I cannot edit.  According to my sources, they say that if the UDID number starts with "ffffffff", it is an incorrect (fake) UDID.  Furthermore, this makes those devices in my Devices list useless and I can't change the UDID to the correct one that I got using iTunes.

It seems to me that Apple should at least allow developers to edit a UDID number if it starts with "ffffffff" because these "fake" UDID numbers take away from the total number of devices I can use for beta testing.

I found all this out because I thought I had the correct UDID number and it was on these iOS devices with UDID numbers starting with "ffffffff" that I could not install my iOS apps onto.

Your thoughts and opinions about this issue and especially if you know of a way to edit UDID numbers.

Thanks.

Comment: I just made the same mistake and now I can't edit/remove the bogus UDID either. This is retarded. I'm trying to figure out whom to contact at Apple to have them manually remove it. It's unacceptable for it to be sitting there wasting a slot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait until the end of your current yearlong Apple Developer License. When next year of your developer license will begin Apple will allow you to remove any devices from the list. But it happens only once every year.